# Optimization with bootstrapping, can it be done like described below?

Tags: bootstrap, simulation

so far I have not used bootstrapping extensively and only know "1-D"-examples, but 
I'm wondering if it might help with the following problem:

Assume I have n customers, and that I conducted several advert campaigns.
For each customer $j$, I have the accumulated costs $C_j$ of the campaigns he participated in and I have the accumulated profit/loss $P_j$ for the customer attributed to these campaigns (marketing costs not yet included).

My goal is: Find the accumulated costs that maximize the accumulated profit for a future marketing campaign.

My idea: bootstrap the data to get a distribution of mean costs and mean profits (or maybe more correctly: to get a distribution of mean profits given mean costs)
From this distribution, I can find the (hidden) mean maximum profit and choose the optimal mean cost accordingly.

Is it okay to use this argumentation?

Comment: I don't see why you would need to use bootstrapping for this.  It seems like a much more straightforward modeling / prediction problem: how does $P$ depend on $C$?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll defintely take a look at a more straigh forward approach. So, let's say I have four levels of cost, but more than 4 customers. For each level of cost, I have some customers and their profits. Hence, for each cost level I have some distribution of profits. However, I don't know the functional relationship of these quantities. I thought, that bootsrapping might help to estimate the true average profit for the cost levels. The optimal level would than be the cost level with the maximal estimated average. But I might fall into the ecological fallacy trap there